# SyntaxError: Unexpected token # while displaying text file

Tags: java, angularjs

My task is to display a simple property file in an html page using AngularJS.
The property files looks something like this :

#

key1=value1

key2=value2

The hash "#" symbol refers to lines with comments in the property file

I m reading the file content and returning the it as a String from my REST api.

```
   @GET
   @Path("/showFile")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String showFile() {
/*some logic */
return content;
}
```

And my Angular code is

```
$scope.getFile = function() {
        $http.get("service/showFile").success(function(content) {
            $scope.fileContent = content;
            console.log(content);
            console.log("Scope variable\n"+$scope.fileContent);
        });
```

I get the file contents correctly from the service, but while parsing the lines with the hash"#" symbol I get the Unexpected token error. Please suggest a workaround to parse '#'.

Comment: so your key contains  # ?

Comment: You have to  *actually parse* the content and turn it into JSON, otherwise the `showFile()` code is returning invalid data (a property file is not a JSON file)

Comment: Not my key exactly. But the comment above the key starts with a hash symbol.

Comment: I m returning the content concatenated in a simple String and I think the conversion of this String into would be done by the REST api where I have specified the content type as MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON. Correct me if I m missing something

Comment: All the `@Produces` tag does is set the response mime type to `application/json`. It does nothing else with it. If you want to return json data, you have to wrap the file content into a json object.

Comment: Thanks Petesh. I think I m simply sending the String back and not converting it into a JSON. However the same works for me when I wrap the String into a List <String> . Any idea why ? Also how can I convert the String into a JSON ? Will my showFile now return a JSONObject if I end up using org.Json library?